# Schneider's Model: What's the differences between stages 3 and 4?

Tags: english, bilingualism

[Schneider's dynamic model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schneider%27s_dynamic_model) gives an account of the evolution of languages in a post-colonial setting.

According to the Wikipedia article, Stage 3 is defined as:

> (3) Contact-induced changes can be achieved by a variety of mechanisms, from code-switching to code alternation to acquisition strategies.

And Stage 4 is defined as:

> (4) Language evolution, and the emergence of contact-induced varieties, can be regarded as speakers making selections from a pool of linguistic variants made available to them.

What are the differences between Schneider's stages 3 and 4? How useful is the distinction?

Comment: References, please?

Comment: Yeah, who is Schneider, and could you summarise these stages? And welcome to the site!

Comment: OK. It seems to me that there are situations where there is a big difference between stages 3 and 4, and others where they're hardly distinguishable. After all, this is a generalized model and makes provisions for all sorts of things that don't always happen.